# sharepoint 2010 getting session timed out error for

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, web-services

We have an application which depends on **“Excel calculation Services”** in SharePoint. This application presents the data from excel to web based format like html. It also gives a text box to insert value which will insert inside the excel file.

This application runs on 2 SP Servers in farm based mode. Many times, we get request timed out issue and not sure what is causing them.

we are using the Sharepoint 2010

when I check the sharepoint server in the eventviewer in the queue application and service logs -> Microsoft-> SharePoint product-> Shared-> Operational

I see the below error

```
Request made on an invalid or timed out session.

[Session: 1.V24.7342/PYx6MnfG6OlnSMayvi290.5.en-US5.en-US73.+0300#0000-11-00-01T02:00:00:0000#+0000#0000-03-00-02T02:00:00:0000#-006036.aac64f12-51a0-4674-aa9e-cf9e1efece901.N

User: 0#.w|test\abc]

event id is 2007
```

also I am getting

```
'd:\excelcache\9e734c77-a44a-4e82-bb55-2acde0ec24fc\Workbooks\3b4b6f86-b752-406e-8c18-97374d168916.xlsx.xlserver' was not deleted while purging the workbook cache. as a warning 

event id is 4967
```

this two are coming continuously

There is a another issue which I saw in Application logs which is a Crictical error

```
The Office HTML Viewer Service could not be registered with Office HTML Load Balancing Service.

Error:  Unable to connect to the remote server
```

with event id : 7933

```
The timer lock for Web server '{65168E97-AFA7-48A2-9A16-5EF389327A0F}' was overridden by Web server '{D06D2ECC-259E-4140-9797-B5CB6762206E}' because the lock had not been refreshed within the 20 minute timeout.  The timer service on '{65168E97-AFA7-48A2-9A16-5EF389327A0F}' may be malfunctioning.
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be a combination of issues.

Firstly, what is the resource utilistaion of the two servers? This could impact the time required to respond to requests.  Secondly, how large are the spreadsheets being analysed by Excel Services? Large spreadsheets could also affect this.

What you may be finding is that the session times out faster than the spreadsheet takes to process.  The session timeout is usually about 30 minutes. So if you have a large spreadsheet, you could [increase the session timeout](http://walkthroughsharepoint2010.blogspot.com.au/2011/08/session-time-out-in-sharepoint-2010.html).
Otherwise, I suggest a health check on the farm, or a resource upgrade to allow processing of data within reasonable timeframes. See the [minimum requirements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485%28office.14%29.aspx) for some guidelines.